# Tegra Ventana Android Kernel power

Tags: android, kernel, tegra

I am having some difficulty in a power file, and I can't see to resolve the issue. I am very new to programming, since I haven't done it since high school with VB. I am helping someone out with a android kernel development under 2.6.39 and most things are going well except we (and by that I mean me) are stuck on this

```
Error

    CC      arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.o
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:110: error: variable 'sm0_config' has initializer but incomplete type
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:111: error: unknown field 'sm_pwm_mode' specified in initializer
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:111: error: 'PWM_DEFAULT_VALUE' undeclared here (not in a function)
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:111: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:111: warning: (near initialization for 'sm0_config')
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:112: error: unknown field 'slew_rate' specified in initializer
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:112: error: 'SLEW_RATE_3520UV_PER_SEC' undeclared here (not in a function)
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:112: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:112: warning: (near initialization for 'sm0_config')
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:115: error: variable 'sm1_config' has initializer but incomplete type
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:120: error: unknown field 'sm_pwm_mode' specified in initializer
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:120: error: 'PWM_ONLY' undeclared here (not in a function)
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:120: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:120: warning: (near initialization for 'sm1_config')
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:121: error: unknown field 'slew_rate' specified in initializer
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:121: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:121: warning: (near initialization for 'sm1_config')
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:161: error: unknown field 'start' specified in initializer
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:161: error: extra brace group at end of initializer
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:161: error: (near initialization for 'rtc_data')
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:165: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:165: warning: (near initialization for 'rtc_data')
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:166: error: unknown field 'cl_sel' specified in initializer
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:166: error: 'TPS6586X_RTC_CL_SEL_1_5PF' undeclared here (not in a function)
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:167: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:167: warning: (near initialization for 'rtc_data')
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:198: error: 'TPS6586X_INT_BASE' undeclared here (not in a function)
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:201: error: 'TPS6586X_GPIO_BASE' undeclared here (not in a function)
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:212: warning: 'enum suspend_stage' declared inside parameter list
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:212: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:212: error: parameter 2 ('stg') has incomplete type
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c: In function 'ventana_board_suspend':
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:214: error: 'TEGRA_SUSPEND_BEFORE_CPU' undeclared (first use in this function)
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:214: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:214: error: for each function it appears in.)
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:215: error: implicit declaration of function 'tegra_console_uart_suspend'
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c: At top level:
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:218: warning: 'enum resume_stage' declared inside parameter list
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:218: error: parameter 2 ('stg') has incomplete type
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c: In function 'ventana_board_resume':
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:220: error: 'TEGRA_RESUME_AFTER_CPU' undeclared (first use in this function)
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:221: error: implicit declaration of function 'tegra_console_uart_resume'
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c: At top level:
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:236: error: unknown field 'board_suspend' specified in initializer
#'error_mark' not supported by pp_c_direct_abstract_declarator#)'arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:236: error: incompatible types when initializing type 'enum tegra_suspend_mode' using type 
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:237: error: unknown field 'board_resume' specified in initializer
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:237: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:237: warning: (near initialization for 'ventana_suspend_data')
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c: In function 'ventana_regulator_init':
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:249: error: implicit declaration of function 'tegra_spare_fuse'
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c: At top level:
arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.c:273: error: 'AC_PRESENT_GPIO' undeclared here (not in a function)
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-ventana-power.o] Error 1
make: *** [arch/arm/mach-tegra] Error 2
```

And here is the code
http://pastebin.com/0V752tu7

Comment: What's the tag for "way out of my depth"?